# Hardware breakpoints on ARM

Tags: debugging, arm

How do hardware breakpoints work on ARM processors? I can see that on x86 and x64 there are 6 DEBUG registers, DR0 throught DR7. Can someone point me to resources [similar to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) but for ARM?

Comment: which architecture/core, no need to expect that from one architecture to another they behave the same.  you have read the arm documentation yes?

Comment: In ARMv6 and later there is at least a standardised debug architecture, as documented in the relevant [Architecture Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/index.html#reference), but the specific details (like number of registers) still depend on what a particular core actually implements; [example picked at random](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0388g/Babdifja.html).

Answer (score 3):

ARM architectures support both Hardware and Software breakpoints. In Cortex A7 (an ARM v7a implementation from ARM) six hardware breakpoints are available. Checkout section: 10.2.2 (Breakpoints and Watchpoints) of the [Cortext A7 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0464d/DDI0464D_cortex_a7_mpcore_r0p3_trm.pdf)

When you run out of hardware breakpoints, there is a BKPT instruction which the debugger inserts to halt execution.

You will have to refer to the **Technical Reference Manual (TRM)** of the particular chip you are looking at for the exact number of hardware breakpoints.