# How many debug registers are available for ARM and MIPS processors?

Tags: debugging, arm, mips, cpu-registers

I know that the Intel X86 have 8 debug registers (DR0 to DR7). 
How many debug registers does ARM and MIPS processors have? what are their names?

Comment: For ARM, it depends on what the particular core implements - see [this recent related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31005781/3156750).

Comment: For MIPS, see Vol 3 of _"MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers"_.

Comment: The MIPS debugging features are a build time option chosen when the processor core is synthesized. Some processor instances have none, some have many.