# Can we watch a read/write of/to a variable in C++

Tags: c++

I have started learning about templates in C++ and am wondering if there is a way to say print out all the read and write to a particular variable just like we can do in CMake. For example, CMake has `variable_watch()` which is used to log all attempts to read or modify a variable.

So my question is that is there a way to do this in C++. If there is no built-in way(provided by the standard C++), then will it be possible to implement it somehow(if so, how?). I mean, if CMake can have this feature then maybe C++ too. Maybe we can make use of template metaprogramming or something else.

Comment: You need to wrap your variable in a wrapper, and that wrapper will log all of the accesses.    That said, it is a lot easier to use a tool to do that.  depending on what exactly you want, you can even set up a watch for variables in your IDE so when debugging you can watch what is happening to the variables.

Comment: You may be looking for the Observer design pattern.

Comment: related: [How to watch a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51278115/995714)

Comment: you could also use a debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do it in C++ without wrapping your variable in something else that logs for you.

But it is possible to do what you need when you are **debugging** your code written in C++ using hardware breakpoints. You can use `watch` in gdb to check accesses to your variable. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb) or [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html). These types of breakpoints are available in Visual Studio too.

Comment: BTW, Visual Studio provides such breakpoints as well

Comment: @YurySchkatula yes, and in much easier way than gdb. :D

Answer (score 2):

Although C++ does not let you attach functionality to reads and/or assignments of variables of built-in types, it has enough features to let you build this functionality for user-defined types.

Specifically, C++ lets you overload assignment and conversion operators. You can build your own template type, say, `Watched<T>`, which has an assignment taking values of type `T` and an implicit conversion operator to `T`. It could also take optional `ReadWatcher<T>` and/or a `WriteWatcher<T>` functions, and call the `ReadWatcher<T>` from the conversion operator, and `WriteWatcher<T>` from the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing,  use your debugger for that. Most debuggers support a special breakpoint that is triggered when the variable is read/written to.